# repo init error in windows 7 with cygwin

Tags: android, cygwin, init, repository

I work in the Windows7 platform, and I want to download the Android source code, so I tried to get it to work together with cygwin + git + repo. But an error occurred while I executed the following code to init the repo tool:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

Error message:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
gpg: keyblock resource `/home/Administrator/.repoconfig/gnupg\secring.gpg': file open error
gpg: keyblock resource `/home/Administrator/.repoconfig/gnupg\pubring.gpg': file open error
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `[stdin]': general error
gpg: import from `[stdin]' failed: general error
gpg: Total number processed: 0
fatal: registering repo maintainer keys failed
```

I looked at the directory for /home/Administrator/.repoconfig/gnupg\ ,and there was nothing!

Has anyone ever had this problem before? What can I do to make it correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you solved that? It looks like gpg for Cygwin doesn't accept backslashes.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  I can confirm that the problem is with the slash.  My error: "gpg: keyblock resource `/home/Molly/.repoconfig/gnupg\pubring.gpg': file open error".  pubring.gpg is there but the \ is being treated like an escape.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. But I installed gnupg and resolved.

I thought that I installed msysgit and system path include msysgit/mingw/bin/gpg.exe file.

So, cygwin shell can reference to incorrect gpg.exe( Not sure :) )

First, you need to execute cygwin setup.exe. And then, check Utils/gnupg and install.

And then retry.

Answer (score 2):

Well turns out my problem was caused by the windows version of git using "\".  I simply uninstalled the windows version of git and then installed git for Cygwin(found under Devel) using the setup program.